# How to change scrollbars in IE10 for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10, scrollbar

So I'm not really a fan of Microsoft's approach on metro-style designing. I recently downloaded IE10 for Windows 7, and overall it looks pretty good. Except for the default scrollbars; this are just ridiculously out of place and unnecessary in my opinion.

Is there any way to change the default scrollbar appearance so that it matches that of IE9 and normal Windows scrollbars?

[image: IE10 on Win7 x64 with classic theme]

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't technically a way to do this, I just went and reverted back to IE9 by going to Add/Remove Programs and clicking on "View Installed Updates". Found Internet Explorer 10 and uninstalled it.